# Reference-Error when compiling kaobook-class in overleaf community edition

Tags: overleaf, kaobook

[raw.log](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/files/13813217/raw.log)

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Installing overleaf community edition using the toolkit and successfully pulling every Texlive package via `tlmgr install scheme-full`
2. Exporting the kaobook-Template from overleaf.com after importing it from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/kaobook)
3. Compiling the files from scratch after clearing the cache

### Expected Behaviour

Successful compilation of a PDF file including correct references and bibliography
The same LaTex project compiles without major errors on overleaf.com

### Observed Behaviour

The references and the bibliography aren't generated properly
When compiling i get the following persistent errors:

`Package hyperref Warning: bookmark level for unknown mtocsection defaults to 0.`

`Citation 'XXX' on page 1 undefined on input line X` ...for very citation

`Empty bibliography on input line 258.`

`Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards.`

I'll attach the raw log file.

Probably the community edition doesn't use or supporting the compileall.sh file of the package that specifies how to compile the document. I'll paste it here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Compile document
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode main

# Compile nomenclature
makeindex main.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o main.nls

# Compile index
makeindex main

# Compile bibliography
biber main

# Compile document
pdflatex main

# Compile glossary
makeglossaries main

# Compile document
pdflatex main
```

### Technical Info

Beside this error the installation works well. The /bin/doctor script included in the toolkit doesn't show any errors

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If you run the compile steps manually (especially biber and then pdflatex again), does it work? If you try a simple document with the `article` documentclass and one citation, does it work?

Comment: When using a regular LaTex document, for example the Overleaf example document, compiling it including a reference and a bibliography works well.

I don't know how to compile the document using the kaobook class manually using overleaf. Could me link me an instruction for that? Unfortunately I didn't find one.

I found out that overleaf uses the latexmk package to compile documents. Could it be a solution to try out a document specific configuration file? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F

Comment: Does the regular document also work with biblatex and biber, or does it use bibtex?

Comment: I tried the example document here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

unfortunately I still get the same errors. I don't know how to manually compile a document using overleaf. The kaobook Template works perfectly well including references and bibliography when using overleaf.com (free AND paid version).

Comment: Is Biber working correctly on your system, can you compile a document with it outside of Overleaf?

Comment: latexmk (and hence Overleaf) usually knows the correct steps for a compilation.  I don't know if it's following the steps in your script.  You might want to reach out to Overleaf support and see what they say.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some further research I found this thread on the overleaf GitHub site: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/1030
Following the instructions there solved the problem for me even though I didn't install another version of biber or python. In fact I updated the packages within the docker container using apt, updated every LaTex package using tlmgr, python packages within the CPAN shell and finally executed the `tlmgr path add` command. Now it works well. I don't know which of these steps solved the issue but as Bomme stated in the final post in the Thread i linked maybe it was the tlmgr path add command.